# How can I undo a 'sudo' command before entering the password?

Tags: sudo

I typed `sudo [bad command]`. The system is asking for my password. I do not want to run this command. How can I exit the password-request prompt?

Comment: press CTRL+C to interrupt the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit out of the password prompt. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> also works, but which one or if both works might depend on your system.