# How can I CTRL^C out of a password prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, kill, authentication

Say I started a `su` command, and I want to cancel it.  <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work for `su` like it does for `sudo`...  I have to finish the prompt (either by getting the password wrong enough times or by getting it right).

Is there something that I can type to kill a password prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I undo a 'sudo' command before entering the password?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256549/how-can-i-undo-a-sudo-command-before-entering-the-password)

Comment: @DisplayName You can't control-c out of a su like you can a sudo... this is a different scenario.

Comment: the answer is control-D.

Comment: @DisplayName Yes, see Gilles answer.  My point is that this should not be marked as a duplicate...

Comment: It is a duplicate. The answer for the post I linked also says control-D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`su` is running with elevated privileges, and you are not seeing it respond to `^C` (which sends a signal with *your* privileges).  You *could* `su` to another shell and kill it from the other shell.  Also (depending on the system), it might respond to `SIGHUP` (a hangup signal) if you closed the terminal session where the awkward `su` is in progress.

There's more than one way that `su` can ignore your `^C`, e.g.,

- establishing signal handlers or
- running under a different controlling terminal.

A quick read of [Debian's `su`](https://sources.debian.org/src/shadow/1:4.5-1.1/src/su.c/) seems that it uses the latter.  Your system of course may be different.

Further reading:

- [/bin/su no longer listens to SIGINT!](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-470147-start-0.html)
- [how to terminate some process which is run with sudo with kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489914/how-to-terminate-some-process-which-is-run-with-sudo-with-kill)

Comment: If I execute `su` as a regular user and it is waiting for a password input from user, is it "running with elevated privileges" at this moment?

Comment: Yes: you can see for yourself by doing a `ps -ef` from another terminal.  That happens automatically because `su` is setuid'd to **root**.

Answer (score 8):

You can `CTRL-D` `su`'s prompt.
This shortcut signals an end-of-file on the console, quitting the prompt; the console will display `Authentication error`, which is expectable.

Comment: Control-D would be an EOF (QUIT is a different thing, and is usually *caught*).  But yes, EOF could work.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the best way to kill `su` during entering of an incorrect password is <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> followed by <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This should avoid annoying delays. You can also just clear the input with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and re-try typing the password in.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is a command that clears the current line of text, and also works in a shell (and probably other places too). It's also nice that it seems to work with `su` to clear the currently-entered password.

Using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't seem to work, it appears that for some reason `su` just ignores it. It is untrue that the user who started the process can no longer kill it because of setuid -- `su` dies perfectly fine if you kill it with `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT` from another terminal (as a user that started it). `SIGINT` doesn't work, so `su` probably just ignores it.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> with an empty password input seems to be the only way to *instantly* kill a running `su` - if any text is entered, then hitting <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will induce a 3-second delay (unless you've actually typed in the correct password, in which case... it'll start a root shell).